# Grep using regex to output phone numbers

Tags: regex, linux, unix, grep, debian

I would like to get the phone numbers from a file of only certain lines.

The numbers are only in this form: `xxxxxxxxxx` but, there is `04` and `05` numbers and i want only `06` and `07` I don't know how to get a uniform regex.

For now, this working but I have `04` and `05` numbers:

```bash
grep -E 'expression.*[0-9]\{10\}' file > output
```

How can I make this command work ?

```bash
grep -E 'expression.*(06)[0-9]\{8\}|(07)[0-9]\{8\}' file > output
```

Comment: If you use POSIX ERE, there is no need escaping range quantifier braces. Try `grep -oP 'expression.*\K\d{10}' file`

Answer (score 0):

You can write it as starting with either 06 or 07 using a character class to match either 6 or 7:

```
expression.*0[67][0-9]{8}
```

Using *grep -E*

```
grep -E 'expression.*0[67][0-9]{8}' file > output
```

To get only the phone numbers using *grep -oP* for a Perl compatible regular expression:

```
grep -oP 'expression.*\K0[67][0-9]{8}' file > output
```